# CupertinoTabView resets on Hot Reload

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino, cupertinotabbar, cupertino-widgets

I am developing an app, using the CupertinoApp model. I am using the CupertinoTabView model for the app. Now during development, the tab index resets on hot reload. I tried setting the state on the tab controller but it still resets.

code:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CupertinoTabController _controller = CupertinoTabController();

    @override
    void dispose() {
      _controller.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }

    List<Widget> tabs = [
      HomeScreen(_controller),
      PlaySearchScreen(),
      HomeScreen(_controller),
      ProfileScreen(),
    ];
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
        controller: _controller,
        tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.play),
              label: 'Play Tennis',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.calendar),
              label: ' My Schedule',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        tabBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CupertinoTabView(
            builder: (ctx) {
              return GestureDetector(
                child: tabs[index],
                onTap: () => setState(
                  () => _controller.index = index,
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen(
    this.controller, {
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final CupertinoTabController controller;

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}
```

Is there a way to not have it reset?

Comment: make the controller from build method to class property. Hot reload reruns the build method, so your controller gets reset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

As ***@p2kr*** pointed out, you got a mix up in your `build` function (since you also have the `dispose` callback inside which you want to define outside the `build` function) and you make use of the `CupertinoTabScaffold` where the documentation states:

> You must listen to the onTap callbacks and call setState with a new
> currentIndex for the new selection to reflect. ***This can also be done
> automatically by wrapping this with a CupertinoTabScaffold.***

taken from [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTabBar-class.html). So my original answer applies if you don't make use of the `CupertinoTabScaffold`. In your case, your class should look like this:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    // Placing the _controller as a property of your class
    // instead of a local variable inside your build method
    // which would be re-instantiated on every build call -
    // as in the case of hot reload
    CupertinoTabController _controller = CupertinoTabController();

    // Also setting the dispose function correctly outside
    // of the build function
    @override
    void dispose() {
        _controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        List<Widget> tabs = [
            HomeScreen(_controller),
            PlaySearchScreen(),
            HomeScreen(_controller),
            ProfileScreen(),
        ];

        ...
```

**ORIGINAL**

The `CupertinoTabBar` has a `currentIndex` property to maintain a selected tab. Therefore you need to add an additional property to your `_HomePageState`:

```dart
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    // Variable to maintain current tab index.
    // Setting it to 0 (first tab) as default here
    int _index = 0;

    ...
}
```

Then in the actual `CupertinoTabBar` we add set the `currentIndex` property and make use of the `onTap` callback to update our property accordingly:

```dart
CupertinoTabBar(
    // Setting the index
    currentIndex: _index,
    // Callback to update our index once a tab is clicked
    onTap: (index) => setState(() => _index = index),
    items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.home),
            label: 'Home',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.play),
            label: 'Play Tennis',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.calendar),
            label: ' My Schedule',
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
        ),
    ],
),
```